# Ranger spells when using sharpshooter archetype

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, homebrew, ranger

In the source of the [ranger archetype (dandwiki)](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Sharpshooter_(5e_Archetype)) it says this:

> At 3rd level your path focuses your magic. Moving forwards you gain the spells at the levels specificied. Once you gain access to the spell(s), this becomes your spell list. You no longer use the Ranger spell list. You also gain the cantrip Druidcraft.

Does this mean that a ranger forgets the spells learned at second level, or can he/she still use these spells?

Comment: Note that the linked page - which redirects to [this one](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Sharpshooter_%285e_Subclass%29) - no longer includes the quoted portion.

Comment: Related: [Why does dandwiki have a poor reputation?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/109306/35259)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## You lose your previously known spells and they are replaced by the listed spells

Just to clarify, this is not an "official" subclass as published by Wizards of the Coast nor is it part of their own designed Unearthed Arcana. It is a homebrew subclass and you should discuss using it at your table and with your DM. It may not be well balanced!