# Poisons and potions, what class?

Tags: dnd-5e, class, poison, potions

Okay, I want to make a person who creates poisons and potions. You ask for a strength potion, and they might give you a strength potion, or they could give you a potion of rage. Or you get something with a crushed werewolf tooth in it so you gain strength, but it's because you now have lycanthropy. And if they didn't like someone, they could just poison them. Chaotic evil, all the way!

From what I have read, there are three kinds of potions. The first are the potions the spell caster creates that replicate spell effects. There is also alchemy, but it seems very close to modern chemistry (identifying poisons, creating soap, etc.) And there is also herbalism, which instead of making poisons, they make cures. And apparently anyone with a poisoner's kit and proficiency in it can make basic potions.

If I could only make potions as a spell caster, I could go with a wizard, maybe a green draconic sorcerer so I could have an affinity with poison.

If I could make poisons with fun side-effects, I would like to be a rogue who poisons people.

Also, I know Alchemist Artificer is a thing, but some people have mixed feelings about it.

Yeah, writing this tells me I'm going to home-brew some potion/poison recipes (I know the ultimate answer to this is run it by the DM), but what is the closest class to the source material should I take? If you have played (or DMed for) someone like this, how did it go?

---

This might not make sense because I made the background before I checked to see if it fit well in an existing D&D class.

This person is a half-elf who decided that the only way they were going to get power in this world was to break society down. A proud and arrogant prince is no longer in line for the throne if someone slips him an elixir of sex shifting and makes his brother next in line. A wealthy and greedy lord will bleed money to cure a mysterious disease. Or they could give rebels potions of dragon's breath and giant's strength. They could cut deals with were-rats to spread a potion to the lower class that gives them super powers. Someone sneaky and underhanded that wants established rule overthrown.

It was a cool idea I had but if this can't fit as a character in D&D, that's okay.

Comment: Have you actually looked at the Artificer UA class for yourself? If so, what specifically did you not like about it? What did not fit what you want? Knowing these things about the most obvious thematic choice for this question will help you get more useful answers.

Comment: Wizards of the Coast's Artificer gets 7 formulas for things that acts like spells. Alchemical acid is a better acid splash, but I'm looking for someone that would discretely give you a poison or potion than someone who throws thunderstones. The True Artificer home-brew on D&D wiki sounds interesting though https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Artificer_(5e_Class)#Tradition_of_the_Alchemist

Comment: I would comment that despite the message, I didn’t think this was necessarily too opinion-based: I voted to put this on hold because I find it kind of unclear, so unclear actually that I couldn’t even say for sure whether or not it really is too opinion-based. More details on what you do—and, seems more relevant here, don’t—want would help a lot.

Comment: Do you own, or have access to, the Dungeon Masters Guide?

Comment: Actually since I am new to this, I ordered a copy from amazon a few days ago to help clarify things (there is so much information!) Is there any part of the guide you had in mind for me to look over?

Comment: Read [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109306/why-does-dandwiki-have-a-poor-reputation) before you use the True Artificer.

Comment: Oh, wow! Good to know!