# Would this homebrew Eldritch Invocation allow you to add Eldritch Blast damage to a sneak attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, warlock, sneak-attack, eldritch-invocations

**NOTE: Homebrew must be allowed for this to work!**

- Take 1 level in Rogue to get Sneak Attack. Take 5 levels in Warlock
  (this is preferably your starting class).
- Take Agonizing Blast at the second Warlock level, as well as whatever
  other invocation you want.
- At fifth level, take the  [dandwiki homebrew Eldritch Blow invocation](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Warlock_Invocations_and_Boons_(5e_Class_Feature)#Eldritch_Blow), which
  goes as follows:

> As an action, you may make a melee attack against a creature, dealing additional damage equal to your eldritch blast's damage on top of the existing weapon damage.

- Get a rapier since sneak attack requires a ranged or finesse weapon.

This should get you 1d8 + DEX piercing, at least another 1d6 due to sneak attack, as well as 2d10 + CHA force damage. I say 2d10 because at 5th level, you get another d10 for Eldritch Blast damage.

This should work, right?

Comment: Just leave the mistake in your post. Since you already have answers that correct it, there is no need to correct it in the question itself. Updating it would mean that the people that have already answered would have to modify their answers to make sense.

Comment: FYI, dandwiki [is not a great resource](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109306/why-does-dandwiki-have-a-poor-reputation).

Comment: Apologies. If I made my own version, or used Blake Steel's idea (with permission), would that be ok?

Comment: When homebrewing, understanding balance is key in development. The stack isn't a great place to develop homebrew (forums are likely much better), but we can [assess balance once you're ready](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8171/how-should-i-ask-about-my-dd-5e-homebrew-being-balanced). Once you get enough Reputation, you can also hop into [chat].

Comment: Specifically, please check [How can I ask a good homebrew review question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8122/1204) section 2 -- iterate in new questions, not via updating the question.

Comment: @LukeSommers: To be clear, it is OK to ask about dandwiki stuff here, but we often are going to have a hard time answering it because stuff there is often poorly designed and may not be written all that well. You can also ask about homebrew you've designed yourself.

Comment: The Eldritch Blow feature allows a "melee attack" but is ambiguous as written (it implies a melee weapon attack but doesn't enforce it consistently) and refers to "your eldritch blast's damage" without explaining how that is calculated (single or multiple blast, with or without damage modifier). The only person who could answer your question factually is whoever wrote the Eldritch Blow feature. Anybody else's answer is opinion.

Answer (score 5):

## Yes, that works as written

The steps all logically work together and the damage does stack up together (just don't forget to add the CHA for each Blast.)

### Most likely incredibly overpowered.

I personally do not think this is balanced as it presents significantly more always-on damage than nearly any other class and every player would likely want to do be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

## It works as you've specified (with one minor change).

Rogue 1/Warlock 5, Agonizing Blast and **Eldritch Blow** (homebrew in question) invocation would indeed cause

> (1d8+DEX + 1d6 from sneak attack) piercing damage + (2d10+(2*CHA)) force damage, for a total of
>
> 1d6 + 1d8 + 2d10 + DEX + 2*CHA damage.
>
> (Agonizing Blast deals CHA on hit, and eldritch blast is 2 hits, so would be 2*CHA).