# Do Hexblade warlocks choose their spells from the Hexblade spell list or the warlock spell list?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, hexblade

Since a warlock hexblade is a subclass (i.e. a special kind of warlock) in D&D 5e, does he choose his spells from the Hexblade spell list? Or can he choose from either the warlock or hexblade lists?

I am leaning toward he chooses from hexblade not warlock as they simply have a hexblade spell list. If he could still cast from the warlock spell list, why make a Hexblade spell list in the first place? Also, please explain the reasoning for your answer. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

So first things first - All warlocks can choose the spells they learn from the warlock spell list regardless of their subclass or patron.

The Hexblade's Expanded Spell List feature says:

> The Hexblade lets you choose from an **expanded list of spells** when you learn a warlock spell. The following spells are **added** to the warlock spell list for you.

(emphasis mine)

This means that you can choose to learn spells from this list if you wish (only if it is your chosen patron). It does not limit you in any way from learning regular warlock spells.

The reason that there is a separate Hexblade spell list is that every patron gives you access to a different set of spells. There is identically a Fiend patron spell list, a Seeker patron spell list and so on for each patron. All of these are **expanded spell lists** which means that they give you more options to choose from and do not limit your choices.

Comment: my apologies yes it is for D&D 5.0. I am new to 5.0 trying to get things right as i am DMing and some of it is confusing at best so in addition to the extended spell list the hexblade can choose from either or both of the splell lists in the PHB marked warlock and hexblade. thank you for the clarification.

Comment: i was confused as i had downloaded some info from a D&D wiki on 5.0 subclasses but it turns out that information was for a particular homebrew type of Hexblade and had its own spell lists to enhance that particular characters powers which i mistook as a set of spell for Hexblades to choose from.My bad.

Comment: @Dennis you may have been looking on dndwiki, I would recommend not using that site as a source as it has a lot of issues including very confusing labeling on what is homebrew or not.

Comment: What Rubiksmoose said. For reference: [Why does dandwiki have a poor reputation?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109306/why-does-dandwiki-have-a-poor-reputation)