# How can I protect myself as a flying archer?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, flight

I will soon play an Aarakocra Arcane Archer ([the custom class](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Arcane_Archer_(5e_Class))) and I am wondering how I can protect myself from mages / other archers as a flying archer.

**I am specifically looking for ways to impose disadvantage on attack rolls against me while flying during combat. Any method which grants cover would also be useful.**

What can I use to protect myself while flying?

I was thinking about putting myself right front of the sun (it's difficult to directly look at the sun, so it should be difficult to aim something right front of it) and eventually cast a Fog Cloud on myself if I'm in danger. What else could work?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Why does dandwiki have a poor reputation?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/109306/10642)

Comment: I'm afraid there are a lot of things that made this either too broad or too opinion based. You want to protect yourself while flying. Putting yourself front of the sun is a good solution, but then you include Fog Cloud. With these combinations, you don't define a limit to the possible answers, causing all answers to be equally correct and basically having unlimited possible answers. Please define a limit, such as 'what spells' or 'what magic item'.

Comment: The question is not about games mechanic or spells or whatever.

It's about how I can justify the fact that my opponent has a disadvantage against me for instance. Fog Cloud is a valid solution because if I cast it on myself, I'm not visible anymore. It's more about roleplay and consistency.

Comment: @cdauphin In that case, perhaps the question could be edited to give that sort of specification there - you want something that would justify an actual disadvantage roll by an opponent. That might narrow down the question, (also has mechanics backing so isn’t just opinion) and help you get the good sort of quality answer you want :)

Comment: Just for future reference: we do not signal edits here as is often done on forums.  The edit history takes care of checking back to see what edits have been made.

Comment: If you're not interested in game mechanics, this is purely an idea-generation question - those are both too broad and primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 2):

## Use distance to your advantage

Most of your opponents are stuck on the 2D plane, while you have extra options. You also have more movement (50 feet) than most enemies. As such, you can determine a minimum distance you can be away from people - if you are 150 feet high, an enemy can't get closer to you than 150 feet.

So, use a longbow (with a range of 150/600). Fly to 150 feet, then directly above your opponent. If they are using any weapon other than a longbow, 150 feet is in the long (disadvantage) range for their weapon. Many spells also have a range shorter than 150 feet - most spells have a range of 120 feet or shorter, and so can't even target you. If they are using a longbow, you can at least force them to use readied actions to attack you if you dart up at the end of your turn, then dart down to fire.

You can also get the Sharpshooter feat - this makes you able to fire without disadvantage from up to 600 feet. This makes most forms of attack impossible against you.

Comment: 150 feet straight up is considerably further than 150 feet horizontal in the real world; a reasonable DM might consider this long range even for a longbow, while being normal range for you.

Comment: @TimLymington Fortunately, real world physics aren't really a consideration :)

Comment: @TimLymington If the DM rules that vertical distance is 'longer' than horizontal distance, that's still fine - if you can only shoot 100 feet high, then fly at 100 feet. It wouldn't work if people shooting up didn't get this disadvantage, but real world physics indicate that that shooting up should be harder than shooting down, not the other way around.