# How do deity/patron granted powers work across different realms?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, planes

As a GM I put my player group into a situation, where they could end up on a different world, in this case they jumped from Faerun to Tamriel. After the game ended one of my players asked me how his cleric powers work.  His deity, in this case Shar, didn't have any influence on this world.
I simply used a pancake analogy: the material planes simply stack on each other and the other planes wrap around it, so Shar could still grant him her blessings.

My question is:
In the case of jumping into another world (e.g. from Faerun to Ravnica) and your patron has no influence there, what happens to your class abilities?  If they are lost or warped, what ways are there to get them back?

Comment: What material are open to considering as authoritative?  Since you are the DM, it's always your call.  For example, are prior edition references useful to you?  Only core books for this edition?  Wayfarer's guid to Eberron?

Comment: I have access to Eberron, non of the til date other unpublished worlds, like greyhawk or dragonlance, but with the power of the internet one might be able to build some interesting adventures in these worlds.

Comment: It's possible, but it would very much help this question if you're looking for just 5e sources or if you want earlier edition lore included. But given the specific question of Faerun to Ravnica, i'm not sure earlier editions would be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

There are no official canonical rulings for D&D 5th edition. However there are official rules for AD&D 2nd Edition that was released as part of [the Spelljammer setting](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/17263/Spelljammer-Adventures-in-Space-2e). These rules could be adapted to D&D 5th edition.

*Page 17 The Concordance of Arcane Space by Jeff Grubb*

> **Clerics in space**
>
> Clerical magic operates normally within the crystal shell that
>   surrounds a cleric 's native world, but is severely hampered once that
>   cleric enters the phlogiston. A cleric receives his spel ls through
>   the offices of his deity , and his deity 's effectiveness ends at the
>   crystal shell. The phlogiston is impenetrable to extra-dimensional
>   magics , and as a result the "gods" and other powers have no sway
>   there.

The rest of the sections goes into explaining that

- Spells already memorized are still retained by the Cleric
- Regaining spells above 2nd level is problematic due the cleric being cut off from their deity.
- There are alternatives like using a *Gate* spell, finding close alternative deities, spreading the cleric's religion, etc.

There are however a wealth of unofficial Spelljammer 5e material on the wider internet. For example [this wiki](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/5E_Spelljammer_(5e_Campaign_Setting)). This [section talks about the author's take on clerical magic](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Special_Rules_(5E_Spelljammer_Setting)).

Comment: Related on dandwiki: [Why does dandwiki have a poor reputation?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/109306/41726). I still like your answer; just thought I'd bring it up since you link to the wiki for possible 5e conversion.

Comment: @DavidCoffron  The spelljammer section is clearly a homebrew set of rules and I stated it as such.

Answer (score 1):

5th Edition doesn't really have an official stance on this, but previous editions have.

The 3rd Edition *Manual of the Planes* has a sidebar on page 44 that discusses this issue, albeit within the context of some specific rules about how clerics worked in that version of the game:

> **DIVINE SPELLCASTING AND ALTERNATE MATERIAL PLANES**
>
> Even if an alternate Material Plane has its own pantheon of deities, divine spellcasters can still gain their spells provided that they have access to their native plane through spells or portals. [...] If a divine spellcaster who receives spells from a deity arrives by interplanar accident, however, the connection may be severed. Such a character might have to locate a new deity that matches up with the alignments and beliefs of his or her old deity before receiving spells again. Certain spells and domains may no longer be available until the switch is made -- and converting to a new faith may not be an easy process.
>
> Alternatively, a cleric cut off from his deity might simply venerate the principles he stands for, connecting to his domains in the same way that clerics unaffiliated with a deity do.

That said, this is 5e, so it's up to the DM to decide what they want to do. As I see it, there are three basic options, of which you might choose one, or mix-and-match various elements of several:

### 1) Your bond to your deity is stronger than planar or multiversal boundaries.

Even if you go somewhere that your god's influence doesn't normally extend to, as a cleric, you bring your god's influence along with you. This is the easiest option; the cleric doesn't have to be concerned with the technicalities of planar travel. As the above sidebar quote said, this could be related to the presence of portals or other semi-permanent planar connections nearby -- as long as the portal is open, you have contact, but if the door closes, you might be stuck with no powers.

But you could easily just make this ruling without worrying about portals and such; just decide that a cleric can talk to their particular deity *no matter what* because that's just how it works in your game.

### 2) Somebody else picks up the slack.

When you arrive in a new multiverse, some other god/entity/philosophical power source becomes your new source of power while you're there based either on your domain choice or some thematic similarity. Shar can't reach you, but instead you start getting power from Nerull or the Raven Queen or The Shadow or just the philosophical concept of darkness itself. This might be just a DM handwave, or it could have some implications on the character, depending on how much you want to get into it as a story element. A connection to a new deity might cause just a mild mystical push to act in ways more associated with the temporary patron, or you might even have a servant of said patron coming to investigate why somebody seems to be drawing their power who isn't properly their cleric.  It could be something the gods have kind of agreed to do behind the scenes or a strange effect that surprises them as much as anyone. Or you could decide that the same deities exist in other multiversal worlds under different guises, so the God of Storms in one world presents as the Goddess of Seas in another world but has similar domains and so on -- "You don't recognize me with this face and form, but I know you."

### 3) You lose your clerical powers, either entirely or partially.

This is probably the worst idea, in my opinion. While you're away from your home multiverse, your powers stop working entirely and you're just a sub-par fighter. This is very likely to feel like you're beating up on Clerics in particular (and, possibly, Paladins), since your fighters, wizards, and bards don't risk losing *their* powers when *they* go to a new world.

You could of course mix these to some degree, like allowing the cleric to use cantrips and low level spells due to a sort of accidental connection to a thematically-similar local deity, while restricting access to powerful magic, but that's still likely to feel like you're being mean to one player in specific.

If you wanted to be slightly more egalitarian, you could rule that the cleric's powers are limited, but so are *all* magic users because arcane and natural magic in this world works a little differently as well. That's still going to sting, but at least it's more "hey Fighter, go be cool" than "welp cleric, you're just gonna suck this time".

It also might depend on the universe you've arrived in. If you pop into Darksun, the fact that clerical magic doesn't work is a pretty big part of the setting, and the Cleric class just doesn't exist there, but arcane magic is also super-restricted. Conversely, Ravnica doesn't have gods as such, and all clerics get their powers from philosophical concepts or the guildpact itself, so there's not much need to spend a ton of effort on converting anything.

Comment: That's very detailed thanks...