# Are there any anti-slavery war deities who also have the Lust domain?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, alignment, religions-and-deities

I'm looking for any deities accepted in 3.5 for my character to follow. The character is also CN if that helps any.   The domains I'm looking for would be lust and battle/war but also hates oppressors and abusers of all kinds due to characters own background as a slave.     Does anyone know of any deities that fit what I'm looking for?    I've tried searching online multiple times but as soon as I put in the lust domain i get a very small list of mostly evil aligned deities. 
No campaign actually set up yet just mostly trying to flesh out my characters bio and abilities.  Making him a drifter and former slave escaped from some evil deity and since then from bits of mismatched lore and gossip he's learned since then. But the main things hes attracted to based on his past are helping the oppressed, battle/war, and lust.

Comment: @BradleyLindsey What's your Class?  If it's Cleric or something similar, it's written in the rules that you can do what I proposed to you.  p.32 of PHB (If your cleric is not devoted to a particular deity, you still select
two domains to represent his spiritual inclinations and abilities. The
restriction on alignment domains still applies)

Comment: Hmmmm. I was debating a barbarian shaman type route.

Comment: @Barker and Maxime: [You should post your recommendations for addressing the underlying issue as answers](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3318/how-do-we-handle-a-desire-to-challenge-the-frame-of-a-question), not [as comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments). (Alternately, such discussions may be better suited to [chat].)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## If you only needed the *War/Lust* Domains:

- You could just be a Cleric without a Patron Deity and worship multiple gods:
- p.32 of the PHB states:

  > (If your cleric is not devoted to a particular deity, you still select
  >   two domains to represent his spiritual inclinations and abilities. The
  >   restriction on alignment domains still applies)
- You could worship a god with the *Lust* Domain and another one for the *War* domain if they don't contradict themselves in their point of view/alignment and your problem would be solved.

### Sidenotes

- @V2Blast suggested that I wrote my suggestion in an answer instead of
  a comment, since this could benefit the community I did it. This
  answer is only to add some info for other people to see.
- Note that nothing prevents you from taking domains even with gods
  that might not be compatible, the only restriction is the alignment
  domains, it is your convictions, and praying the gods in general is a
  valid option

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that [this list](https://web.archive.org/web/20150910043951/http://home.comcast.net/%7Eftm3/ASMoNM/domains.html) is accurate, your options for Lust are:

> Core Deities: Gruumsh, Lolth, Olidammara.
>
> Eberron Deities: Olladra.
>
> Forgotten Realms Deities: Beshaba, Eilistraee, Hanali Celanil, Hathor, Isis, Lliira, Loviatar, Luthic, Sharess, Sharindlar, Sheela Peryroyl, Sune.
>
> Other Deities: None.

and your options for War are:

> Core Deities: Corellon Larethian, Erythnul, Gruumsh, Heironeous, Hextor.
>
> Eberron Deities: Dol Arrah, Dol Dorn, the Mockery.
>
> Forgotten Realms Deities: Anhur, Arvoreen, Clangeddin Silverbeard, Deep Duerra, Gaerdal Ironhand, Garagos, Gorm Gulthyn, Haela Brightaxe, Ilneval, Laduguer, Red Knight, Selvetarm, Shevarash, Solonor Thelandira, Tempus, Tyr, Uthgar.
>
> Other Deities: Azor'alq, Beltar, Gelf Darkhearth, Hruggek, Joramy, Kaelthiere, Mayaheine, Panzuriel, Sekolah, Stronmaus, Surtr, Taiia, Thrym, Wastri, Xan Yae, Zarus, Zuoken.

from intersecting these two lists, we see that Gruumish is your only option, but what little I know of his lore suggests that he is unfitting.

Personally, I would suggest that you consult a list of domains and find some similar domains that fit your needs. You mentioned a Battle domain in your question, but I do not know of one. However, there are some other options that seem fitting. There's so many other possibilities that it would take a great deal of time to make an exhaustive list: Glory, Liberation, Passion, Pleasure, Protection, Retribution, Seduction, Spite, Temptation... You get the idea.

Comment: That list is generally *very* accurate, but I’m not sure where Olladra is given Lust *or* War—neither *Eberron Campaign Setting* nor *Faiths of Eberron* notes those domains as among his cleric’s options. As “The Sovereign of Feast and Fortune,” neither seems entirely appropriate, either.

Comment: Just out of curiosity I just looked it up a bit using both google and the tool above and I'm curious of an Anarch is a class, or race because the Kratos entry makes them seem like basically a CN paladin but when I looked it up on google it seems like a subrace of human.              I'm asking because from what ive read i was thinking that the best fits for my character would be to be devoted to two deities and if allowed I was thinking Kratos and Eilistraee

Comment: @BradleyLindsey As far as I can tell, yours is the only usage of “anarch” on this page, so I’m not sure where that came from, but if you have more questions, it is best to ask them as a Question. Though for a question along the lines of “where’s this X I heard about?” it’s important to include where you heard about it (link and quotation, usually), so we can see context.

Comment: Also, about Gruumsh—he’s rather _pro_-slavery, so yes, a terrible choice. You may want to mention that in your answer.

Comment: I think it was here: https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Kratos_(3.5e_Deity)

Comment: @BradleyLindsey DnD Wiki is not a good source.

Comment: Thats what i was afraid of. But he is also in the playstore complete 5e reference app. And someone said its pretty easy to port to 3.5.

Comment: @BradleyLindsey: See also: [Why does dandwiki have a poor reputation?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109306/why-does-dandwiki-have-a-poor-reputation)

Answer (score 2):

Most Chaotic deities are going to be pretty anti-slavery, particularly the Good ones. And almost all deities, almost by definition, support martial endeavors—the world of D&D is a violent place, and one of the things mortals turn to deities for is answers to the violence—and that almost always means violence of their own.

For example, Sune Firehair is the CG goddess of love in the Forgotten Realms, and while she doesn't focus on slavery per se, she certainly opposes it. And she has Protection, Guardian, and even Combat along her domains or portfolios in various editions (Protection in 3.5e). She also has an order of knights dedicated to her. That’s alongside her Lust and Pleasure domains.

Anyway, the most useful and thorough resource for finding deities in 3.5e is [IMarvinTPA’s Find Deity tool](http://imarvintpa.com/dndLive/FindDeity.php). You can search by alignment, domain, and so on to find deities there. For example, searching for deities that are NG, CG, or CN and have the Lust domain (“Sin-Lust” in the tool) results in several deities:

- Eilistraee, Forgotten Realms, CG goddess of good drow.
- Hanali Celanil, FR, CG elven goddess of love and beauty.
- Hathor, “Pharaonic” (Egyptian), goddess of *a whole lot*, including the sky, the sun, maternity, fertility, cattle, royalty, and revenge.
- Isis, Pharaonic, queen goddess, later than Hathor and supplanted her in some ways
- Lliira, FR, “lady of joy” and former exarch of Sune. Unusually non-violent.
- Olidammara, Greyhawk/“default” D&D, god of rogues.
- Sharess, FR, flirtatious cat-goddess once known as “Bast” (the Mulhorandi pantheon in FR is largely identical to the real-world Egyptian one), corrupted by Shar and then later redeemed by Sune.
- Sharindlar, FR, dwarven fertility goddess.
- Sune, FR, described above.

Sune is probably the best fit of these, but you can play with the tool to find other stuff. Maybe the Pleasure domain has better results than Lust, or Charm, or Passion. Or maybe it’s better to look for deities with, say, Liberation, and see how sexual they are or are not. Having done a little digging (a bit more than I want to write up), though, I suspect Sune is probably your best bet unless you’re drow.

Comment: thanks I think that may be just what I'm looking for.    I downloaded the playstore app for the 5e reference tool and tried to do the same for 3.5 but the problem was that the only one that I could find that even says its compatible with 3.5 is the d20 app and its mostly just tools and weapons stuff like that no races or deities at all that I could find.  And I'm unsure about what in 5 is applicable for 3.5 or if the deities listed in the 5e app are even canon to 5e.  I mean Boosh with his high priests Old Gregg?  Or Kratos the God of War?  Ya know?

Comment: @BradleyLindsey 5e deities are... usually more-or-less compatible with 3.5e. 4e messed with the canon *hard*, but 5e retconned *most* of that away. But 3.5e is likely to have more options, just by dint of having more sourcebooks and having been around longer.