# Samurai use of two-handed weapon

Tags: dnd-5e

I found a homebrew Samurai class on dandwiki.com; which can be found at this link: https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Samurai_(5e_Class)#Fighting_Stance

At the time of asking this, Earth Stance allows you to use a two-handed weapons with one hand:

> While you are in this stance, you have advantage on Strength checks made to grapple and can hold a two-handed weapon in one hand whilst grappling a creature. Additionally, on one attack per turn, you may use your bonus action to gain a bonus to your AC equal to your proficiency modifier if the attack hit. This bonus AC lasts until the start of your next turn. Also while in this stance your feet are planted firmly on the ground, doing this grants advantage on Strength saving throws and disadvantage on Dexterity saving throws.

Is the second attack made normally or at disadvantage?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take our [tour] to learn more about how things work here. Just so you are aware, dandwiki is not a source of official D&D 5e rules. The class you are referencing is not created by Wizards of the Coast, or a recognized third party; instead being a part of the homebrew section of the website you got it from. We can try to answer this question based on the text from that page, but it will be difficult to provide rules answers since dandwiki typically has lower quality of work than official sources.

Comment: What do you mean by "second attack"?  No attacks are affected or added by this stance, just an effect that you may trigger (via bonus action) on an attack

Comment: FYI, [dandwiki has a very poor reputation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109306/). That may be something to consider when looking on their website.

Comment: What level is your character?

Comment: This answer is suitable, and answering misconceptions is a common thing we do. I voted to leave open -from review.

Comment: Yikes. Just what I'd expect from an inexperienced amateur game designer. This one stance has five separate rules to remember, two of which include conditionals, and the stance feature itself has a whole bevy of rules and exceptions on top of that. Much too complex, and that's not even considering the unclear writing and downright incorrect grammar. "This page is considered complete and balanced"?  It would need heavy editing just to be coherent!  I'm restraining myself from rewriting the stance to be usable.

Answer (score 12):

That part of **Earth Stance** is a poorly written<sup>1</sup>, superfluous ability that actually does nothing.

The Two-Handed [weapon property](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#WeaponProperties) says...

> This weapon requires two hands when you attack with it.

The statement...

> can hold a two-handed weapon in one hand

...is something any character can do anyway. There's nothing requiring two hands to *hold* a weapon with the property, only to *attack* with it.

That said... There's nothing in there about a second attack, so the answer to...

> Is the second attack made normally or at disadvantage?

...is "Neither, because there is no second attack as part of Earth Stance."

If you're talking about an attack via **Extra Attack**, we've already established that the ability doesn't actually let you make an attack with a two-handed weapon if you're holding it with one hand.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Much of the content on that website falls into the [poorly written category](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109306/why-does-dandwiki-have-a-poor-reputation). The very name of the site is poorly written (there's a missing "d", resulting in "d-an-d" rather than "d-and-d").</sub>

Comment: And despite all this, there's a content notice on the page itself saying "This page is considered complete and balanced. As such, the page has been locked so that only administrators can edit it"...

Comment: @StopBeingEvil Yeah, requested by the person who wrote it. :)

Comment: D&D wiki *strike again*

Comment: @RevenantBacon You mean "D& wiki". There's only two Ds, not three. :)