# How do you cast Mending on a clockwork character?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, homebrew, cantrips, healing

I'm playing a DnD campaign (my first real one). My DM is pretty new to it as well and we are unsure of the following rules and how they work together.

I am playing a custom race: [Clockwork](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Clockwork_(5e_Race)). I realise this might not be the best idea since we're new to DnD but here we are...

Anyway, my character is also an artificer with a mending cantrip.

The clockwork race has a trait called Made to Mend which stops you from dying if someone casts mending on you.

But how does **healing** work if I want to heal after a battle? How much does it heal and how many times do I need to cast it?

I'm made purely out of mechanical components so I should obviously be able to use any means that normally fix mechanical components to heal, right?

We can assume that the damage in quesion is all to non magical faculties of my player (i.e. I don't have to wory about Mending's limitation on restoring magical properties).

Comment: Worth noting is that *Mending* has a casting time of 1 minute, i.e. 10 rounds. If someone started casting *Mending* while you were already dying, it's nearly impossible for you to still be alive but unstable by the time they finish casting it. (The only way for this to happen is if you stabilize in the meantime and then take another hit, causing you to become unstable a 2nd time.) I very much doubt the person who came up with this race was aware that *Mending* takes 10 rounds to cast when they designed this feature, so I would echo the other recommendations not to play this homebrew race.

Comment: Note also that [DandDWiki does not have a good reputation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/109306/3548).

Comment: Another vote for "this will not be fun for either of you". Anybody can make up anything on that site, and there's no guarantee it works or is balanced. You're new, your DM's new, and I would strongly suggest you play one of the official races. As others have said, Warforged would be closest in concept, but honestly if you want to take the stats of a human etc and just describe yourself as being made from clockwork, with no mechanical effect, I'd be fine with that as a DM.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Given that this is a homebrew race, it seems unlikely (and, in fact, completely impossible) that the game is actually designed to take it into account, and homebrew content frequently has issues with things that would come up in play-testing. As far as the content present *only* in the class, there is no way to answer this question; whoever created this race didn't seem to make provisions for healing.

However, per *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron*, warforged can be healed via all the same methods as an organic adventurer (healing magic, healers kits, and resting). Warforged are humanoid constructs, as are the clockworks, so I believe it's reasonable to extrapolate between the two.

(I would also suggest that you just play a warforged with clockwork flavor, for the sake of simplicity and balance, especially as a newer player, but that's not the question you asked.)

Comment: I second the suggestion of using the stats for Warforged. Homebrewing on your first campaign is a recipe for an un-balanced, un-fun experience, and without a lot of system knowledge it can be hard to identify what the root problem is. It's a lot safer to use some professionally produced material first.

Comment: The linked homebrew rules for Clockwork don't give them the "humanoid construct" trait of benefiting from healing. In fact, they effectively say the default Clockwork *doesn't* benefit from healing, because one of the *Maker's Mark* traits they can select (*Alchemical Blood*) is the one that lets them count as humanoid for the purposes of healing; it follows that the intent is that all Clockwork *without* that trait count purely as constructs, and can't be healed by any of the common healing magic.

Answer (score 16):

#### The Made to Mend feature just doesn't make sense.

The Made to Mend feature states:

> Made to Mend. When a creature casts the mending cantrip on you, you instead become stable if you are dying.

*The mending cantrip has a casting time of 1 minute*. It takes ten rounds of combat to cast *mending*. If you go down, and someone starts casting *mending*, you will either be dead or stabilized through saving throws before *mending* can finish casting - your fate is decided in at most five rounds (3 success, two failure, or vice-versa).

I would highly recommend just playing one of the officially published races for your first campaign. Good homebrew is rare, and good homebrew from dandwiki is non-existent.

Comment: I am very tempted to downvote for the last sentence, despite an otherwise good answer.

Comment: As Ryan [noted in comments](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/191109/how-do-you-cast-mending-on-a-clockwork-character#comment514273_191109), the only way you can be unstable when Mending completes is if you stabilize on your own, then take another hit and become unstable again before the casting time completes.

Comment: Or perhaps the intent was that the process of *starting* to cast Mending means that improvement is happening, i.e. that it's a gradual knitting over 1 minute, not 1 minute of nothing and then instantly healed the way magic normally works (cast time then instant duration).  But most likely this was just a design error from not double-checking Mending.

Comment: @PeterCordes Maybe, but like, 10 rounds worth of using your action to cast a cantrip is still just an impossibly stupid choice to make.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov: Nobody has argued that was reasonable, just technically possible.  (The worst kind of possible.)  When I commented earlier, I had thought that your answer's phrasing implied there was no way the feature could ever help at all, but your phrasing is still compatible with that silly case.  So there isn't anything worth nitpicking, just a funny example of how extremely bad this design is.

Comment: @PeterCordes Was I not strong enough in my language? *There is no way the feature could ever help at all*. There are exactly zero use cases for the feature where the caster of *mending* could not be more useful by doing literally anything else.

Answer (score 11):

Per the rules you linked, by default, you're a construct, and therefore, per the rules for most (all?) of the healing spells provided so far, you can't be magically healed. *Mending* only stabilizes, it doesn't heal, so that doesn't help.

Seems like the only way to be magically healed is if you selected the *Alchemical Blood* trait as one of your *Maker's Marks*:

> Alchemical Blood: You have an alchemical mixture that keeps you running. Despite your construct nature, you are considered humanoid when a creature casts a spell to grant you hit points.

In practice, being healable is basically necessary to function in most D&D campaigns, so almost all playable Clockworks would take *Alchemical Blood*. Which sounds like a limitation, but most of the other *Maker's Marks* are so bad/useless that you're not missing out on much.

I'll second the suggestion from others that you avoid homebrew for your first campaign. If you want to play a living construct, play a Warforged, which isn't nearly so complicated/poorly thought out.

Comment: @NautArch: "***Heart of Steel.*** Your creature type is construct instead of humanoid." (it continues, but the rest is irrelevant)

Answer (score 8):

### Homebrew and Rules

I'll start by saying that any time you use homebrew you run into the large grey void of rules that may or may not work depending on what your homebrew says. In this case, just apply the idea that specific beats general and that your homebrew override rules as they are written. Now for the questions at hand.

##### How much does mending heal?

Quite simply, it heals nothing at all. The trait states that Mending can be used to stabilize a dying clockwork character. While stable, you regain 1 hp after 1d4 hours and return to consciousness. However, you can't heal by being mended. This is outside the scope of both the spell and the trait in this homebrew.

##### A note about Clockwork

Clockwork have the *interesting* trait of being Constructs. Normally this doesn't mean much. However, this prevents most magical healing. I would implore you and your dm talk about this since adventurers often need magical healing in some form.

Answer (score 7):

## Healing is not the same as treating injuries

Healing in DnD 5e is the recovery of lost hit-points. Hit-points do not necessarily represent your physical condition, but rather

> a combination of physical and mental durability, the will to live, and luck

So when you say

> I'm made purely out of mechanical components so I should obviously be able to use any means that normally fix mechanical components to heal, right?

I would point out that physically fixing your mechanical components does not necessarily restore your physical and mental durability, will to live, and luck.

Let's look at some other precedence to show that in regular (organic) characters, healing and physically "fixing" someone are not the same:

- Not every physical ailment reduces hit-points. Diseases, like sight rot, damage your body but don't reduce hit-points. Being petrified (which sounds pretty damaging to one's body) doesn't reduce hit-points either.
- Not every remedy to physical ailments restores hit-points. A Healer's kit contains bandages, salves, and splints. You use them to mend physical injuries such that a character is stabilized, but it does not restore any hit-points. Greater Restoration can remove statuses like petrified. But it doesn't restore hit-points
- Not every damage to your hit-points is physical. Psychic damage reduces hit-points just like any other damage, but does not cause any physical damage that could be fixed. So, if loss of hit-points are not necessarily caused by physical damage, then physical restoration does not necessarily restore lost hit-points.
- Not every healing restores all physical ailments. If a character lost a leg, a simple Cure Wounds will not make the leg reappear, even if it happens to heal you all the way back to max HP. You need specialized spells, like Regenerate to repair the limb.

### Of course you can homebrew that it does

All of the above is just to say that fixing yourself does not **obviously** also heal you. However, there is nothing intrinsically wrong with homebrewing a race where it does. Whether or not that is balanced is another topic. Due to its casting time (1min) it's probably not very useful in-combat. Seeing how it is a cantrip, though, I think it would be severely overpowered out-of-combat. You'd essentially have unlimited out-of-combat heal, something that (to the best of my knowledge) is not available to any other race or class.

Answer (score 5):

By the description you linked, Mending does nothing if you are stable.

From [this discussion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/dungeons-dragons-discussion/rules-game-mechanics/24747-how-do-you-heal-constructs) we see that

> The Nimblewright from Waterdeep: Dragon Heist is a construct that has the repairable feature, which allows for mending to heal one hit point.

Your race does not have this feature, so as it is written it does not work for you. Of course you and your DM may decide your character does now have it,  homebrew problems usually require homebrew solutions.

Also, nothing in the description of the race you are playing seems to prevent most ways of healing available for other player races, like Potions of Healing or spending HD during rest, or long rest benefits.

Spells that explicitly don't work on constructs won't work though, as the The Heart of Steel makes you a full construct, not a Humanoid (living construct) for example.